# Using threads on C++ on Raspbian, Can't compile

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to make a simple TCP server program for my Raspberry Pi 2. I already made the initial server code and it works, but then, I tried to implement a thread exclusively for the server and I haven't been able to compile since then.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int serverTask(int port){
    int n;
    char buffer[256];
    /* Socket File Descriptors */
    int socketFd, socketFdNew;
    socklen_t clientLength;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;

    /* TCP Socket */
    socketFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socketFd < 0){
        error("ERROR opening socket\n");
    }

    /* Fills serverAddress with zeroes */
    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));

    /* ServerAddress configuration */
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* Biding socket to server address */
    if(bind(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0){
        error("ERROR on binding");
    }

    /* Listen for incoming connections, 5 is the number of queued devices */
    listen(socketFd,5);

    /* accept freezes the running thread until a client is found */
    clientLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
    socketFdNew = accept(socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientLength);
    if (socketFd < 0){
        error("ERROR on accept");
    }

    /* Fill buffer with zeroes */
    bzero(buffer,256);

    /* Reads up to 255 characters in the socket */
    n = read(socketFdNew, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0){
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }

    printf("Received: %s\n",buffer);

    /* Responds with placeholder value */
    n = write(socketFdNew,"40.12\n",7);
    if (n < 0){
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
    close(socketFdNew);
    close(socketFd);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread serverTask(7000);

    std::cout <<"Hello World!\n";

    serverTask.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My first attempt was simply building the code as any other code using `g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp"`

Which got me the following error:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:35:0,
>                    from main.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++
>   standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be
>   enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
>   main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:79:2: error: 'thread' is
>   not a member of 'std' main.cpp:79:14: error: expected ';' before
>   'serverTask' main.cpp:84:13: error: request for member 'join' in
>   'serverTask', which is of non-class type 'int(int)' Compilation
>   failed.

So then I tried using `C++11`, so I recompiled with `g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -pthread -o "main" "main.cpp"` and I got the following:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:39:0,
>                    from main.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In member function 'void std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__call(std::tuple<_Args ...>&&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes
>   ...>, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type) [with _Res = void, _Args = {},
>   int ..._Indexes = {}, _Result = void, _Functor = int, _Bound_args =
>   {}, typename std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::__enable_if_void<_Res>::type = int]':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1378:24:   instantiated from
>   'std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type
>   std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}, _Result = void,
>   _Functor = int, _Bound_args = {}, std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::result_type = void]' /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:117:13:   instantiated from 'void
>   std::thread::_Impl<_Callable>::_M_run() [with _Callable =
>   std::_Bind_result]' main.cpp:86:1:   instantiated from
>   here /usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1287:4: error:
>   '((std::_Bind_result*)this)->std::_Bind_result::_M_f' cannot be used as a function Compilation failed.

My last resort was installing g++4.9. Once installed, I tried with `g++-4.9 -Wall -std=gnu++0x -pthread -o "main" "main.cpp"` and I got the following result:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
>                    from main.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from
>   'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int;
>   _Args = {}]' main.cpp:79:29:   required from here /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named 'type'
>   in 'class std::result_of'
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
>                                                                ^ /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named 'type' in
>   'class std::result_of'
>            _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
>            ^ Compilation failed.

Now I'm confused and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

## Update 1: Trying with a simpler code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>


int serverTask(int port){
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread serverTask(7000);


    std::cout <<"Hello World!\n";

    serverTask.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The results remained the same:

> g++-4.9 -Wall -std=gnu++0x -pthread -o "test" "test.cpp" (in
>   directory: /home/pi/TempServer) In file included from
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
>                    from test.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from
>   'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int;
>   _Args = {}]' test.cpp:12:29:   required from here /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named 'type'
>   in 'class std::result_of'
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
>                                                                ^ /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named 'type' in
>   'class std::result_of'
>            _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
>            ^ Compilation failed.

Comment: Try to make a simpler example, e.g. if you ise `int serverTask(int port){ return 0; }` and take out all the necessary includes, do you still get the same errors?

Comment: @M.M: Alright, I just tried that, got exactly the same result, I also removed the libraries used.

Comment: OK, update your post to include the simpler version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
std::thread serverTask(7000);
```

declares a variable called `serverTask` and you try to pass `7000` as the name of the function to run in the thread. However `7000` is not a function. Unfortunately g++ gives very cryptic error messages here.

You probably meant:

```
std::thread foo(serverTask, 7000);
```

to start a thread with the function call `serverTask(7000)`.

Comment: Whoops, It was something so simple... I totally misread the page I was using for [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/), sorry, and thanks! I tested it and it works fine!